# h2o build failed on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, h2o

I am trying to build h2o source code for ubuntu 16.04.

Here is the output :

```
:h2o-r:classes UP-TO-DATE
:h2o-r:jar UP-TO-DATE
:h2o-r:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:h2o-r:getRVersion
:h2o-r:gitbranch
:h2o-r:pdflatex
:h2o-r:setProperties
    Git Branch: master
    R Version: 3.3.3
    PDF LATEX: /usr/bin/pdflatex
:h2o-r:cpH2OAppJar
:h2o-r:setDevPackageFiles
:h2o-r:setPackageFiles
:h2o-r:buildPackageDocumentation FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':h2o-r:buildPackageDocumentation'.
> Process 'command 'R'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 33.713 secs

Task timings:
  14.641 secs  :h2o-assemblies:main:shadowJar
   8.099 secs  :h2o-bindings:runGenerateRESTAPIBindingsSrc
   4.404 secs  :h2o-py:buildDist
   1.360 secs  :h2o-web:installNpmPackages
   0.780 secs  :h2o-py:verifyDependencies
   0.771 secs  :h2o-bindings:compileJava
   0.596 secs  :h2o-assemblies:main:copyJar
   1.585 secs  All others
```

I have installed all prerequisites. Its able to build all packages & breaks down at documentation. How can I fix this?

Comment: I've removed the `java` tag as this question does not relate to Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the repo, there is a complete H2o2 dev environment implemented in Docker
based on 16.04. In the same folder there is an Ubuntu 16.04 setup script.

http://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/docker/setup-h2o-dev.sh

Comment: Both answers are very useful & correct, but this is much easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. To resolve it I
renamed my  `~/.Rprofile` file (even if it is the default one)

I have two R versions on my machine, R 3.2.2 and R 3.3.3, this confused the build script.

So to make things simpler for the build script
, I ran it with a modified PATH variable, successfully!

(What's puzzling is it still used R 3.2.2  although in /usr/bin is R 3.3.3! However, the installation continued)

```
export PATH=/home/knut/.virtualenvs/h2oai/bin:/home/knut/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.4/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin  && ./gradlew build -x test
```

I've excluded (-x test) the tests, because they fail while spinning up a multinode cluster on my machine (java runs out of memory)

Result:

```
    :buildSrc:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
    ... many many UP-to-DATEs ....
    :h2o-r:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-r:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-r:processResources UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-r:classes UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-r:jar UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-r:assemble UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-r:getRVersion
    :h2o-r:gitbranch
    :h2o-r:pdflatex
    :h2o-r:setProperties
        Git Branch: master
        R Version: 3.2.2
        PDF LATEX: /usr/bin/pdflatex
    :h2o-r:cpH2OAppJar
    :h2o-r:setDevPackageFiles
    :h2o-r:setPackageFiles
    :h2o-r:buildPackageDocumentation     ####### here it exited previously, now continues
    :h2o-r:buildPackageDocumentation took 3.828 secs
    :h2o-r:genPDF
    :h2o-r:genPDF took 4.432 secs
    :h2o-r:cpPDF
    :h2o-r:buildPKG

    :h2o-r:buildPKG took 3.454 secs
    :h2o-r:cpToR
    :h2o-r:publishPKG
    :h2o-r:untar
    :h2o-r:cleaner
    :h2o-r:build_rh2o
    :h2o-r:check
    :h2o-r:build
    :h2o-scala_2.10:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-scala_2.10:compileScala UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-scala_2.10:processResources UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-scala_2.10:classes UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-scala_2.10:jar UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-scala_2.10:assemble UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-scala_2.10:check
    :h2o-scala_2.10:build
    :h2o-scala_2.11:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-scala_2.11:compileScala UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-scala_2.11:processResources UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-scala_2.11:classes UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-scala_2.11:jar UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-scala_2.11:assemble UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-scala_2.11:check
    :h2o-scala_2.11:build
    :h2o-test-accuracy:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-test-accuracy:processResources UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-test-accuracy:classes UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-test-accuracy:jar UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-test-accuracy:assemble UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-test-accuracy:check
    :h2o-test-accuracy:build
    :h2o-test-integ:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-test-integ:processResources UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-test-integ:classes UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-test-integ:jar UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-test-integ:assemble UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-test-integ:check
    :h2o-test-integ:build
    :h2o-web:assemble UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-web:check
    :h2o-web:compileAndInstallDocFiles
    :h2o-web:build
    :h2o-assemblies:main:assemble
    :h2o-assemblies:main:check
    :h2o-assemblies:main:build
    :h2o-hadoop:h2o-mapreduce-generic:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-hadoop:h2o-mapreduce-generic:processResources UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-hadoop:h2o-mapreduce-generic:classes UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-hadoop:h2o-mapreduce-generic:jar UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-hadoop:h2o-mapreduce-generic:assemble UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-hadoop:h2o-mapreduce-generic:check
    :h2o-hadoop:h2o-mapreduce-generic:build
    :h2o-hadoop:h2o-yarn-generic:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-hadoop:h2o-yarn-generic:processResources UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-hadoop:h2o-yarn-generic:classes UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-hadoop:h2o-yarn-generic:jar UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-hadoop:h2o-yarn-generic:assemble UP-TO-DATE
    :h2o-hadoop:h2o-yarn-generic:check
    :h2o-hadoop:h2o-yarn-generic:build

    BUILD SUCCESSFUL

    Total time: 31.37 secs

    Task timings:
       9.241 secs  :h2o-assemblies:main:shadowJar
       4.432 secs  :h2o-r:genPDF
       3.828 secs  :h2o-r:buildPackageDocumentation
       3.598 secs  :h2o-bindings:runGenerateRESTAPIBindingsSrc
       3.454 secs  :h2o-r:buildPKG
       2.083 secs  :h2o-py:buildDist
       0.922 secs  :h2o-web:installNpmPackages
       3.073 secs  All others
```

Then I installed it with `R CMD INSTALL h2o-r/R/src/contrib/h2o_3.11.0.99999.tar.gz` into R 3.3

If this still does not succeed, run

`./gradlew build -x test --info`

and update your question with the relevant output

Comment: I haven't customized my R installation. Its just a direct `apt` install with a few packages added that were needed. How can I confirm if it is a pdflatex issue?

Comment: I'm afraid, I don't know. Maybe install rstudio? It brings a whole lot of software with it in order to render Rmarkdown as PDF. In Rstudio,  generate a simple Rmarkdown file and "knit" as PDF. If this works, you probably have a working PDFlatex infrastructure.

Comment: I was able to successfully knit the pdf. Although a few R packages were needed, they didn't help make the h2o problem go away :(. Atleast pdflatex isn't the problem.

Comment: I'll try to build h2o.ai from source myself, first time. I also have a Ubuntu 16.04. May take a while.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to sync R packags:

```
git clone https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3.git
cd h2o-3
./gradlew syncSmalldata
./gradlew syncRPackages
./gradlew build
```

Reference:
https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3